# TSQL How do I create a new table from two existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TSQL How do I create a new table from two existing table? Want a new table
Called EmployeeInfo that has the information from both EmploeeDemographics and  EmployeeSalary

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[EmploeeDemographics]
right outer join [dbo].[EmployeeSalary] 
    on EmploeeDemographics.EmployeeID=EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID
```

Comment: `SELECT * INTO [newTableName] FROM ...` But you will need to mention the columns explicitly, because `EmployeeID` exists in both, and column names need to be unique

Comment: But why? Generally speaking, the goal of a relational database is to **remove** duplication.

Comment: @SMor  This is just a basic mock example. I need to create a new temp table from bunch of queries which I can then connect into using spark for example  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/data-sources/apache-spark-sql-connector.  This then allows me to get the data i want for ml in one table as I can read it as a dataframe.